# uneven space between words

Tags: spacing

when I use itemise or enumerate the spacing between the words reduces when compared to the remaining content outside the itemise or enumerate loop .i want same spacing as outside content

.[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You need to provide sample code that demonstrates this behavior, rather than just a picture.

Comment: that is not the default behaviour. You must be using some package to increase the line spacing in normal text but revert it to normal in lists. If you don't say which code you are using to do that it is hard to say what to change.

Comment: Take a look at this http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that for the basic, what is expected, for questions.  However, for your question you should probably not change the \documentclass to "article", if it is not already "article", as it looks like you may be having some package interaction issues.

Comment: yeah its the style that is mentioned while defining the format of the document.